# selection sort loop questions in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, selection-sort

I have a basic question about the inner loop length in Java selection sort. Here is the commonly used code for selection sort:

```
package com.java2novice.algos;

public class MySelectionSort {

    public static int[] doSelectionSort(int[] arr) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            int index = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
            /* why not the length is not arr.length-1? I think the length is
               exactly the same as what it is, the array's length is a 
               static number as array.length-1, but when it comes to the inner
               loop why it plus 1 to the array length? */

                if (arr[j] < arr[index])
                    index = j;

            int smallerNumber = arr[index];
            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = smallerNumber;
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to do, and what problems you are having. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I think the length of the inner loop should be as the same as the array length as well, which is a stable value as array.length -1, why when it comes to inner loop being added to 1 to the length of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you're trying to sort five items. The array length is 5, which means the indexes are 0 through 4.

In the first iteration of the inner loop, you have `i=0` and `j=1`. You need `j` to index to the end of the array. That's why the expression in the inner loop is `j < array.Length`.

`i`, of course, only goes from 0 to 3, which is why the outer loop has `i < array.Length - 1`.

If you lay five playing cards on a table and walk through the steps of the selection sort, you'll get a better idea of what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

the first loop does not need to check the last index, therefore, it goes to `arr.length - 1`. on the second loop, of course, the last index of the array must be checked so the loop goes to the last index (`arr.length`).
imagine if the first loop goes to the last index. then this line `for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)` will never execute.
check out this Pseudo code of selection sort for a better understanding of the algorithm
[image]